# How to extract the filetype of a content-URI

Tags: java, android, uri

My activity receives a content URI like

**content://data/thing/something/2342365356**

If another app shares anything with an **image/*** intentfilter.

But if an user selects one picture and one video on google photos and shares it, the intent is still image/jpg and my app crashes. I want to go thorugh the URI-array and figure out what type of File they lead to and handle it appropiately. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Call [`getType()` on a `ContentResolver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#getType(android.net.Uri)), passing in the `Uri`, to find out the MIME type associated by the content identified by that `Uri`.

Also note that a `Uri` is not a file, and the content identified by the `Uri` does not need to be a file.

Comment: If the mime type is image/* or video/* it has to be a file though, right? I will ignore everything else.

Comment: @Tomhawk: "If the mime type is image/* or video/* it has to be a file though, right?" -- no. It could be content managed by Google Drive that has not been downloaded to the device yet. It could be content out on a SMB/CIFS file server on a Windows-style network. It could be content in an encrypted content store. Even in cases where it is a file, it may not be in a location on the filesystem that you can access (e.g., some other app's portion of removable storage).